# I have a plot embedded in my Tkinter GUI, Im trying to add to the plot a crosshair that shows where the mouse is

Tags: python, tkinter, pylance

On a normal Plot the crosshair is working very well
[see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVwK1.png)

But when my plot is embadded in the GUI aka not a seperate window it does not display it. one of the warnings that im getting for the code is **"cursor" is not accessedPylance**

`cursor = Cursor(plot, useblit=True, horizOn=True, vertOn=True, color="green", linewidth=2.0)`

My code for the plot part :

```
        figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
        plot = figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        figure.suptitle(Date, fontsize=12)
        plot.plot(x, y, color=Color)                                

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, root)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=4,y=200)

        
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root, pack_toolbar=False)
        toolbar.update()
        toolbar.place(x=4,y=600)

        cursor = Cursor(plot, useblit=True, horizOn=True, vertOn=True, color="green", linewidth=2.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Cursor` is inherited from `AxesWidget` and according to the [document of AxesWidget](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.AxesWidget):

> To guarantee that the widget remains responsive and not garbage-collected, a reference to the object should be maintained by the user.

So If your code is inside a function, then you need to keep a reference of the cursor.  Try:

```
plot.cursor = Cursor(plot, useblit=True, horizOn=True, vertOn=True, color="green", linewidth=2.0)
```

It uses an attribute of `plot` to save a reference of the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without looking at everything, but my guess would be that the `Cursor` class isn't imported or you're assigning the **cursor** variable and never using it.

Comment: seems like a comment